# RISC - V : Is there any way to parse a word to a float?

Tags: riscv

I am trying to divide a float to a word

```
  fmul.s f8, f2, s5
```

every time I try to run it an error pops up mentioning
`Too few or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: fmul.d f1, f2, f3, dyn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to first convert the word value into a float with an fcvt instruction:

```
fcvt.s.w  f1, x5
```

then you can use a normal floating point `fmul` or `fdiv` instruction